# Count value across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I am looking to count the number of times set of values occurred in a table.  These values could occur in up to 10 different columns.  I need to increment the count regardless of which column it is in. I know how I could count if they were all in the same column but not spanning multiple columns.

Values can be added in any order.  I have about a thousand

```
Cpt1    Cpt2    Cpt3    Cpt4    Cpt5
63047   63048   63048   NULL    NULL
```

I would want to for this row I'd expect this as the result

```
63047 1 
63048 2
```

Comment: Please add an example of the data an expected output

Comment: Most likely a bad database design. Are you sure your data is properly normalized?

Comment: Please include sample data as well as desired output.   Guessing at schema would make this question a fool's errand

Comment: How big is your table?

Comment: table i'm reading from is probably 6k lines with about 1k different codes to look at

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `union all` call to treat them as one column:

```
SELECT   col, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT col1 FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT col2 FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT col3 FROM mytable
          -- etc...
         ) t
GROUP BY col
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your table exactly looks like, but I'm guessing that what you're looking for is:

```
SELECT row_count = COUNT(*),
       row_count_with_given_value = SUM ( CASE WHEN field1 = 'myValue' THEN 1 
                                               WHEN field2 = 'myValue' THEN 1
                                               WHEN field3 = 'myValue' THEN 1
                                               WHEN field4 = 'myValue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM myTable
```

Assuming the `fieldx` columns are not NULL-able, you could write it like this too:

```
SELECT row_count = COUNT(*),
       row_count_with_given_value = SUM ( CASE WHEN 'myValue' IN (field1, field2, field3, field4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work (after adapting to your value domain and data types):

```
create table t1 
(i1 int,
 i2 int,
 i3 int);

 insert into t1 values (1,0,0);
 insert into t1 values (1,1,1);
 insert into t1 values (1,0,0);

 declare @i int = 0;
 select @i = @i + i1 + i2 + i3 from t1;

 print @i;

 drop table t1;
```

Output is: 5

Comment: You're assuming MySQL or another RDBMS that supports in-line assignments.

Comment: @PM77-1 I am not assuming. The question is tagged with sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

Many databases support lateral joins, of one type of another.  These can be used to simplify this operation.  Using the SQL Server/Oracle 12C syntax:

```
select v.cpt, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (cpt1), (cpt2), . . . 
     ) v(cpt)
where cpt is not null
group by v.cpt;
```

Comment: interesting.  will check this out.    this is in sqlserver 16